# Single Drupal installation with multiple websites

Tags: 7, theming, panels, multi-sites

Currently, I have two static HTML folders: 1 for English webiste , and 2 for Thai website. They have the same look and feel but different menu and content. To be precise, the menu and content
in the www.example.org/th are not translated versions of the English site, they are totally different.

URL for the English website is http://www.example.org and http://www.example.org/th for the Thai website.
I want to switch to Drupal 7. So, here's what I have in the to-do list:

Theme:

- Create a parent theme (www.exaple.org)
- Create a sub theme for (www.example.org/th)

Panel:

- I will create a Panel with "th" path for www.example.org/th and then make it use the subtheme (not sure if this is the correct approach)
- Create a different menu and will put it in the Panel (not sure if this will work out that way)

Should I create Panel and different menu or Should I go with single Drupal installation that can be used to power multiple websites to get the same result as I currently have with static HTML sites? 
If so, please show me some tips or sample to get started.

Thank you.

Comment: Even if you sites will not have the same content and navigation, are there parts that you *do* want to be the same? For instance users, taxonomy terms, node types or views?

Comment: No. They don't have the share anything. Now, that you asked me this question, it's clear that I should have two different installations.

Comment: In that case I agree with @Berdir's answer. Just create two completely separate sites.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, if these two sites are really separate and have nothing in common, I would go with a multi-site setup and a single Drupal installation.

This is supported out of the box, see the [Multi-site documentation](http://drupal.org/documentation/install/multi-site) on drupal.org for more information.

Comment: @Naranza wants www.example.org for one site and www.example.org/th for the other, but I'm not sure if multisite would be a solution. A multisite installation could handle www.example.org and th.example.org for instance, but can it put a separate site in a subdirectory?

Comment: @marcvangend: It's possible with sme Apache configuration, see for example http://www.drupalcoder.com/blog/drupal-multisite-in-subfolders. And if that doesn't work, you could still install two separate installations, only downside is that you need to update both separately.